# How to use git revert to go back to third commit?

Tags: git

I merged some bad files 2 commits ago. I wish to bring my branch back to the state it was at the 3rd last commit.

I have looked up the commit hash and tried:

`git revert 112233445556etc` but get the error:

> error: Commit 112233445556etcis a merge but no -m option was given.
>   fatal: revert failed

I can't seem to find any information on Google, apart from git revert.

Would anyone know of the correct way to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`git checkout HEAD~3` would let you revert back to three commits ago. You are currently on `HEAD` and `HEAD~n` takes you back n commits. or in your case you know the commit-id so you can do a `git checkout 112233445556etc`